# The power cut while I am running my code, and all the code is erased even the one I already saved!!! .. How can I get the code back?

Tags: beamer

The power cut while I am running my code, and all the code is erased even the one I already saved!!! .. How  can I get the code back ?

Comment: Well, first of all i advice you to make a copy of all your project-relevant files and folders on an USB Stick an put that one in a drawer. Just to be safe.

Comment: That sucks big time but I don't think you can. This happened to me with TeXnicCenter on Win machine before. I don't know about other systems.

Comment: @percusse Is it possible, that the files are gone to nirvana completely? I hope not, since a files are saved before compiling?

Comment: Not to be rude but how has this got anything to do with (La)TeX?

Comment: I sort of agree with @SvendTveskæg, and there is probably a greater chance of getting help on another site (perhaps [SuperUser?](http://superuser.com/)). You should state what operating system you use though.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg @ TorbjørnT. I haven't thought about that, but you are right. This is something OS dependent and has nothing to do with LaTeX.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg @ Johannes_B  @ TorbjørnT.  I didn't know that it is OS problem thank you guys for your reply.

Comment: I use VIM as an editor. It writes a recovery/swap file after every 4 sec of idle time or so. This allows to recover from almost all kinds of accident, even from voluntarily pulling the USB stick containing the file you are currently working on in the middle of an editing session. See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/recover.html.

Comment: As others have said, this is off-topic as it's about basic file recover. Good luck with that!

Comment: As @AlexG suggested: Use `Autosave` feature with `5 or 10 min/sec` timer present ( I assume) in almost all [LaTeX editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) it should automatically save `file.tex.bak` every 5 or 10 min so anytime you may have power shutdown you may lost last 5 min work rather than whole `.tex` doc. Note: In LaTeX once we have `.tex` and `images` you can generate `.pdf` at a later stage easily.

Comment: @JosephWright Just some thoughts on big-list editors: May be imp `autosave` feature is missing in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides and may be added to feature list http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3254/15717