# TeX editor with line-spacing preferences

Tags: editors

Do you know a TeX editor where one can increase the line spacing/change the line spacing in preferences?

LibreOffice Writer could do the trick provided it did not prepend `0xfeff` to files encoded in `UTF-8`, which prevents LaTeX engines from working.

I'm happy with VIm. It's just that I like writing prose in a double-spaced environment.

Comment: I do not have another idea than a mean suggestion: Go through [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides), do own research for every editor and write an answer yourself. ;-)

Comment: @Speravir may be this thread should be updated with [big-list Q](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides) and added separately in each editor answer as **Feature** `Line-Spacing Preference: Yes/No` with an link to this Q.

Comment: @texenthusiast: Good idea, but let's wait a bit. Perhaps some more editors are added here, and the separate answer should be merged in.

Comment: @Speravir Even  Feature: `AutoSave` is missing for big-list Q for all editors which is very imp.

Comment: I have made comment here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161020/the-power-cut-while-i-am-running-my-code-and-all-the-code-is-erased-even-the-on#comment368440_161020 but may be later we should add in template http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3254/15717

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Feel free to enhance the list.*

***Preface:*** For general overview see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/).

## Multi-platform

- In [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), the line spacing can be set with the [`line-spacing`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Line-Height.html#Line-Height) variable.  To change its value, add the following to your `.emacs` (`5` stands for the number of pixels put below lines):

  ```
  (setq-default line-spacing 5)
  ```
- [GVim](http://www.vim.org/), use:

  `:set linespace=12`
- [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) – Under *Utilities: Global options: Text area* you'll find *Extra vertical lines spacing (in pixels)*.
- [sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/) (a commercial text editor with syntax highlighting) – Add "line_padding_bottom: 10", to the user's preferences.
- [TeXstudio](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/) – Go to menu “Options” —> “Configure TeXstudio…”, then on tab “Editor” you find an entry “Line spacing” (default is 100%).

## Linux/Unix

## MacOs X

## Windows

- [SynWrite](http://www.uvviewsoft.com/synwrite/) (a general text editor with syntax highlighting) – Go to menu “Options” —> “Customize…”, then in settings window on “Editor” —> “View Settings” and change the value for “Line spacing” (default is 1).
- [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) – Go to menu “Options” —> “Preferences”, then on tab “Font” and modify the value of “Extra Line Spacing“ (default is 1).

  [image: Screenshot of Winedt Preferences window]

Comment: Texstudio in windows increase only the lower part of the line, but does not increase the upper part. My Unicode characters still be invisible in some circumstances

Comment: Note that for TexStudio you have to enable `Show Advanced Options` in the lower left corner of the `Configure TeXstudio` screen.